# Function pointers with template arguments and return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Look at this code:

```
struct TestStructure
{
    char mName[256];
    int mSize;

    // Store function pointer with templated argument.
    // Store function pointer with templated return type.
};

class TestClass
{
public:
    void setTestInt(const int& value) { mTestInt = value; }
    const int& getTestInt() const { return mTestInt; }
    void setTestFloat(const float& value) { mTestFloat = value; }
    const float& getTestFloat() const { return mTestFloat; }

    static TestStructure* getTestStructure()
    {
        static TestStructure testStructure[] =
        {
            {"mTestInt", sizeof(int), /* setTestInt pointer, getTestInt pointer */},
            {"mTestFloat", sizeof(float), /* setTestFloat pointer, getTestFloat pointer */}
        };

        return testStructure;
    }

private:
    int mTestInt;
    float mTestFloat;
};
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to store inside the *TestStructure* the function pointers to the various getters and setters of the class (and it must work for any kind of type).

There's a way to do that?

Comment: I see no trace of a `template` within your code.

Comment: You are right, but that's the point of my question. How can I use templates to achieve my goal?

Comment: No, there's no way to do that. You can make the struct a template, but then you can't store different instantiations in an array. You need to rethink your design.

Comment: @molbdnilo it actually may be possible with `tuple`s, I'm in the process of trying to implement it.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question but does std::function meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

*Seeing as though it's nearly 2015 and you are probably just learning C++ now: use a C++14 compliant compiler and this code will work.*

Just use a tuple for storing the function pointers

```
template<typename ... Types>
class test_class{
    public:
        template<typename T>
        void set(const T &t){std::get<T>(m_values) = t;}

        template<typename T>
        T &get(){return std::get<T>(m_values);}

        using getters_setters_type = std::pair<std::tuple<Types &(test_class::*)()...>, std::tuple<void (test_class::*)(const Types&)...>>;

        getters_setters_type &getters_and_setters(){
            getters_setters_type ret{
                std::make_tuple(&test_class::get<Types>...),
                std::make_tuple(&test_class::set<Types>...)
            };
            return ret;
        }

    private:
        std::tuple<Types...> m_values;
};
```

then as an example

```
int main(){
    test_class<int, float> test_if;
    auto &&getters_and_setters = test_if.getters_and_setters();

    std::function<void(const int&)> set_int(std::bind(std::get<0>(std::get<0>(getters_and_setters)), &test_if, std::placeholders::_1));
    std::function<int&()> get_int(std::bind(std::get<0>(std::get<1>(getters_and_setters)), &test_if));

    // set int to 5
    set_int(5);

    // check it worked
    if(get_int() != 5)
        std::cerr << "dub tee eff, man!" << std::endl;
}
```

Now, I'll admit; this is rather disgusting to look at... but it does what you asked :D putting the `tuple`s into a `struct` rather than a `pair` would be trivial.

**EDIT**

I couldn't just leave the answer in that morbid state; one could easily write some helper functions to increase readability:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Types>
std::function<T&()> get_getter(test_class<Types...> &t){
    return std::bind(
        std::get<T&(test_class<Types...>::*)()>(std::get<0>(t.getters_and_setters())), &t
    );
}

template<typename T, typename ... Types>
std::function<void(const T&)> get_setter(test_class<Types...> &t){
    return std::bind(
        std::get<void(test_class<Types...>::*)(const T&)>(std::get<1>(t.getters_and_setters())), &t, std::placeholders::_1
    );
}
```

Then in your main function you can write

```
int main(){
    test_class<int, float> test_if;

    auto get_int = get_getter<int>(test_if);
    auto set_int = get_setter<int>(test_if);

    set_int(5);
    if(get_int() != 5)
        std::cerr << "dub tee eff, man!" << std::endl;
}
```

which doesn't look too bad at all!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but I can't implement this solution (that require a C++14 compliant compiler).
I need to find another way (rethinking the design).